# Calling multiple Bash aliases

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, bash

I want to open three different folders on three new terminals from my terminal using one command. All of them should run independently of each other meaning one command does not depend on the one before it.

Here is my .bash_aliases, which is called from .bashrc

```
alias cmd1=gnome-terminal && cd ~/Desktop/

alias cmd2=gnome-terminal && cd ~/Documents/

alias cmd3=gnome-terminal && cd ~/Music/

alias runcmds='cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3'
```

But this opens up three terminals in the Music directory and doesn't execute the commands correctly. How can I make it so that runcmds runs all 3 commands separately from each other?

Also, when do I need to use quotation marks and when do I not need to?

Comment: ...uh. `gnome-terminal && cd ~/Desktop` doesn't run the `cd` *inside* the new terminal, which is what I imagine you want. Instead, it runs a new terminal, and does a `cd` inside the *separate, external process that started the terminal* -- an entirely different shell.

Comment: As for when you do and don't need quotation marks -- `alias cmd1=gnome-terminal && cd ~/Desktop` first makes `cmd1` an alias for `gnome-terminal`, and then changes the directory to `~/Desktop` in the shell in which that alias is defined. By contrast, `alias cmd1='gnome-terminal && cd ~/Desktop'` would `cd` to `~/Desktop` when the alias is invoked, as opposed to when it's defined.

Comment: Understanding [how quotes work in Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) is going to be critical to your success as a shell programmer. If you're unsure when to use them there are numerous resources available online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your order of operations is backwards: You need to `cd` **before** you start the terminals, if you want the new shells within those terminals to be impacted by the `cd`. Moreover, you need to quote, to ensure that both commands -- the `cd` and the invocation of `gnome-terminal` -- are considered part of the alias.

```
alias cmd1='cd ~/Desktop/ && gnome-terminal'
alias cmd2='cd ~/Documents/ && gnome-terminal'
alias cmd3='cd ~/Music/ && gnome-terminal'
alias runcmds='cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3'
```

By the way, I'd suggest -- strongly -- not using aliases at all, and defining functions instead:

```
cmd1() { cd ~/Desktop && gnome-terminal; }
cmd2() { cd ~/Documents && gnome-terminal; }
cmd3() { cd ~/Music && gnome-terminal; }
runcmds() { cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3 & }
```

No quoting involved whatsoever (the final `&`, as opposed to a final `;`, prevents the parent shell's location to being changed to `~/Music` by ensuring that `cmd3`, like the others, runs in a subshell). Of course, you could just implement one function:

```
runcmds() {
  local dir
  for dir in ~/Desktop ~/Documents ~/Music; do
    (cd "$dir" && exec gnome-terminal) &
  done
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually `gnome-terminal` facilitates the `--working-directory` option.

From `man gnome-terminal`:

> --working-directory=DIRNAME
>        Set the terminal's working directory to DIRNAME.

You can use alias as follows:

```
alias cmd1='gnome-terminal --working-directory="$HOME/Desktop"'
alias cmd2='gnome-terminal --working-directory="$HOME/Documents"'
alias cmd3='gnome-terminal --working-directory="$HOME/Music"'
alias runcmds='cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3'
```